# Why am I required to reference this assembly?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

This involves three separate assemblies.

In `AssemblyA`, I have `InterfaceA`.

`InterfaceA` inherits an interface from `AssemblyB` called `InterfaceB` as well as another interface from `AssemblyA` called `InterfaceAWithMethod`.  i.e.

```
Public Interface InterfaceA
    Inherits InterfaceAWithMethod, InterfaceB

    Function MainMethod() As Boolean
End Interface

Public Interface InterfaceAWithMethod
    Function DoStuff() As Boolean
End interface
```

and in the above `AssemblyA` has a reference to `AssemblyB`.

Now, I have a separate assembly called `AssemblyC`.  `AssemblyC` has a reference to `AssemblyB`, and works with an instance of `InterfaceA`.  I use a repository to get an instance of `InterfaceA`, and then call `DoStuff()` on my instance.

```
Dim myInstanceOfA = myRepo.GetInterfaceAInstance()
myInstanceOfA.MainMethod() 'There is no error here.
myInstanceOfA.DoStuff()    'I DO get an error here.
```

Visual studio fully recognizes the method `DoStuff()`, but claims that there is an error here, specifically

> Reference required to assembly 'AssemblyB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the type `InterfaceB`.  Add one to your project

`DoStuff` has NO references to anything in `AssemblyB` and is from `AssemblyA`, why am I required to reference `AssemblyB`?  Additionally, why does `MainMethod` work without a reference, when it also simply lives in `AssemblyA` and has nothing to do with `AssemblyB`?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler requires a reference to avoid ambiguity if the class is defined in more than one DLL and ***or assembly***. When using `inheritance` like this, there can be potential issues: using base classes from inheritance along with just the class itself and circular references to name a few; the compiler can't resolve which one to use.

Your only option at this point is to include the name of the unreferenced DLL or assembly in your project references to make the compiler happy or rethink your approach.

Comment: Why does the compiler need a reference to resolve `DoStuff`, but not `MainMethod`?  Are you saying this is because there is an indentically named `InterfaceAWithMethod` in `AssemblyB`?  There is not, but there is an identically named `InterfaceA` in `AssemblyB`.  Really appreciate the help, btw.